# Highcharts - Zoom to secounds?

Tags: highcharts, zooming

My series data looks like this:

```
[Date.UTC(2017,03,25,09,32,21),0.7695],
//Date.UTC(yyyy,MM,dd,hh,mm,ss)
...
...
```

but I can only zoom till the days......

How can i zomm till the secounds?

Comment: Your code is not complete and it will be hard to give you a better answer than I already did. Read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can also try to change [xAxis.minRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.minRange) to 1000 - but without your code it is a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set

```
tickInterval: 1000
```

and mingRange to at least 1000(1 second)

```
minRange: 1000
```

I made a fiddle with a zoom button, right bellow the chart to the left, that will zoom to the center of the chart showing the seconds, or you can manually zoom multiple times until you can see the seconds(about 5-6 times)
http://jsfiddle.net/vv0weLcn/5/

The data i used was your starting point, then i added 1 hour, 100 times

Answer (score -1):

You can zoom as far as your data let you do this - so this is really depends on your data granularity. Zooming is about setting min/max in your axis scale.

```
series: [{
    pointStart: Date.UTC(2016, 1, 1),
    pointInterval: 1000, // point every 1 sec
    data: [...Array(1000)].map(() => Math.random()) // 1000 points with random values
}]
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/vxg315oj/